# Clients fail to use Pi-Hole or Pi-Hole gets jumped over (a.k.a. oh noes ads show up)

Tags: networking, dns, openwrt, pihole

I have an OpenWRT Router so I followed [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/av1qd4/setting_up_pihole_on_openwrt/) tutorial to setup my Pi-Hole and router, so that all DNS traffic gets redirected as well. When I go to my Pi-Hole and under tab Network I see my device as green (meaning it's using Pi-Hole) but some ads still show up. Is this because the browser is using DNS-over-HTTPS, which the firewall rule does not include? How do I fix this?

Comment: @Anaksunaman in the mean time I have posted on Pi-Hole Discourse and the problem got solved. See my answer below for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem was that my phone was setting two DNS servers instead of one - one was a IPv6 (NOT my Pi-Hole) and another one was a IPv4 address of my Pi-Hole. The solution for my case was disabling IPv6 since my ISP does not support it. On my OpenWrt Router I had to disable IPv6 using the following commands:

```
uci set 'network.lan.ipv6=off'
uci set 'network.wan.ipv6=off'
uci set 'dhcp.lan.dhcpv6=disabled'
/etc/init.d/odhcpd disable
uci commit
```